# Creating a circle within a 2D MATLAB array of data

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry

I have a code that I've written that defines the center of a 2D array of some image I have (the matrix is created from a TIFF image, with intensities of each pixel correlating to each x, y in the array). I am hoping to create a circle from the center of the image, which I find with a function I have written. From the center, I would like to create a circle with an edge one pixel/value 'thick', and then integrate the values of this circle, excluding the center. Then, I would increase the radius by one pixel and do the same. However, I am not certain how to do this efficiently, can anybody point me in the right direction? I am using MATLAB to accomplish this, but am uncertain if transitioning to polar coordinates will help simplify this or if I should stick to Cartesian coordinates. Thank you.

Comment: How should circle with "edge one pixel/value thick" look like at 45 degree radius? Try to fill cells at the paper and you'll see that problem is ambiguous, so exact specification is needed.

Comment: In addition to MBo's valid comment above; do you want a one-to-one mapping, in which each pixel from the image contributes to a single integral over a circle? Or would it be fine if a pixel's value was used in multiple summations, perhaps with a weighting function?

Comment: this link might help you https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98665-how-do-i-plot-a-circle-with-a-given-radius-and-center

Comment: @user8190410 Try to draw 3-4 circles with consequent radii (for example 19,20,21) in integer cordinates (array cells) and look at empty places (and perhaps double-drawn cells)